How to get access to "ForkJoinPool" that schedules virtual threads
ForkJoinPool.commonPool()

returns reference to the common pool which is used for running streams. Is there a way get the reference to access the ForkJoinPool which schedules the virtual threads. Basically I wanna do getStealCount and access other properties of the pool.

Why cant you do 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool().getStealCount());' ?

@JCompetence because that pool is different than virtual thread fork-join pool. Virtual threads are not executed in the commomPool.

That seems to be impossible as the access to constructors and methods of VirtualThread and VirtualThreadBuilder that accept arbitrary Executor is java.lang-package and thus is carefully and seemingly deliberately protected. And those classes are not public, of course. The only customization we could get is via system properties jdk.virtualThreadScheduler.parallelism, maxPoolSize, and minRunnable. See VirtualThread.createDefaultScheduler for the details.

The use of a Fork/Join pool is an implementation detail. The next Java version might use a different backend executor. So, no, there is no API to access that pool.

@igor.zh My only intention is to get steal count in case of virtual threads. Thanks for confirming there is no API to do that for now.

That I figured. What I meant is that if you can configure VirtualThread with your own Executor then you could have an access to anything. BTW, it is very easy to access VirtualThread.scheduler field with Reflection, and from it you could have the steal count or whatever you want.  For exploratory purposes it might be OK. If you are interested I could post a snippet. In fact, your question is very valid.

@igor.zh Thanks. I got the count using reflection.  Thanks for pointing in the right direction.
